# How can I find out the number of times an RSK transaction has been confirmed on the RSK blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, rpc, rsk

It would be good to know how many times a transaction has been confirmed on the RSK blockchain so that when one user sends RIF to another wallet or to an exchange wallet for example we can see how many confirmations have occurred

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also do it with web3.js. As function

```
const getTxConfirmations = (txHash) => Promise.all([
    web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash).then(tx => tx.blockNumber),
    web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
]).then(([blockNumber, currentBlockNumber]) => (currentBlockNumber - blockNumber))
```

And with Truffle console:

```
truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getTransaction('0x7a28a121c41085ef52d449f64120dbc422ec70b4d324c076c8d89222cf7188c8').then(tx => tx.blockNumber)
1
truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
5
truffle(develop)> const getTxConfirmations = (txHash) => Promise.all([web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash).then(tx => tx.blockNumber), web3.eth.getBlockNumber()]).then(([blockNumber, currentBlockNumber]) => (currentBlockNumber - blockNumber))
undefined
truffle(develop)> getTxConfirmations('0x7a28a121c41085ef52d449f64120dbc422ec70b4d324c076c8d89222cf7188c8')
4
```

Answer (score 10):

Transactions do not have a confirmation count per se, but the blocks that they are a part of do indeed have confirmation counts. Thus, the solution lies in "comparing" the **block number** of a particular transaction.

### Using curl

There are several ways to do this,
and the easiest method is the `eth_getTransactionByHash` JSON-RPC method:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0xf1ebb8076ad289fbaef4406bb0488be0c5605a58cfa2a6d11540b1f9b0d7ef98"],"id":1}' \
  https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co
```

The above cURL command is for transaction `0xf1ebb8076ad289fbaef4406bb0488be0c5605a58cfa2a6d11540b1f9b0d7ef98` on the RSK Testnet.
The response is copied below:

```json
{
   "result" : {
      "input" : "0xcbf8...(redacted)",
      "nonce" : "0xda62",
      "blockNumber" : "0x17fe5c",
      "gasPrice" : "0x3938700",
      "hash" : "0xf1ebb8076ad289fbaef4406bb0488be0c5605a58cfa2a6d11540b1f9b0d7ef98",
      "blockHash" : "0xede9aa2ff4939482186d4e6bd269582352a923db13ef90ad7def0d0dec17a239",
      "r" : "0x8c98a16250d157db1fb11e1304684943796710e3f1292a4fb60a0711692f2b8f",
      "value" : "0x0",
      "s" : "0x49cdc35f66dbea2ba88e3c52dc3f4c68498b844dd79eebafc326803e7163f7fc",
      "transactionIndex" : "0x0",
      "gas" : "0x17c65",
      "from" : "0xd761cc1ceb991631d431f6dde54f07828f2e61d2",
      "to" : "0x8bf2f24afbb9dbe4f2a54fd72748fc797bb91f81",
      "v" : "0x1c"
   },
   "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
   "id" : 1
}
```

From `"blockNumber" : "0x17fe5c"` we know that the block number of this particular block is `1572444`.

The next step is to compare this block number of this transaction to the latest block number.
To do so, we need to use a different JSON-RPC request.

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' \
  https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co
```

```json
{
   "id" : 1,
   "result" : "0x180208",
   "jsonrpc" : "2.0"
}
```

From `"result" : "0x180208"` we know that the block number of the most recent block is `1573384`.

```sh
node -e "console.log(0x180208 - 0x17fe5c);"
940
```

We subtract the transaction's block number
from the latest block number,
which yields the answer:
`940` in this case - the number of confirmations.

### Using web3

You can do the same using web3 (different hash in the example, mainnet):

```sh
web3.eth.getTransaction("0x9117f2fab63c89676b6538a317d0b9ec74cc4ac8f375c80c0f2b57223cbd6bb2")
```

```json
{ hash: '0x9117f2fab63c89676b6538a317d0b9ec74cc4ac8f375c80c0f2b57223cbd6bb2',
  nonce: 118329,
  blockHash: '0x02c40394a7ed66bc50a0f1853220a395efd1e3cfebea5e0ff36dd5a0a12b2aeb',
  blockNumber: 3089723,
  transactionIndex: 1,
  from: '0x64DCC3BCbeaE8ce586CaBDef79104986bEAFcaD6',
  to: '0xBEd51D83CC4676660e3fc3819dfAD8238549B975',
  gas: 2000000,
  gasPrice: '60000000',
  value: '0',
  input: '0x5a686699000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032d5284006bf8730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060214e2a000000000000000000000000504efcadfb020d6bbaec8a5c5bb21453719d0e00',
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0x2faaa315b1b3cd7421db1dc5fa243ddfae906282872c2bd9207e7e2dfed8286e',
  s: '0x571fa5a28a48755bdf93aacd28d8d7d8986b1e2db0f5450e2355e7f3c91db30b' }
```

In this case, you get `3089723` from `blockNumber`

Now, you query the current best block:

```sh
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(console.log)
```

```json
3089747
```

And, therefore, you have `3089747 - 3089723 = 24` confirmations.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if my response will be the best, but this is an option do find it.

I usually search in the [explorer.rsk.co](https://explorer.rsk.co/)

- First you can check the block number which your transaction was mined
- After you can view the last block mined.
- The difference between the block numbers is the number of confirmations

I hope it is useful to you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same using web3 (different hash in the example, mainnet):

```sh
web3.eth.getTransaction("0x9117f2fab63c89676b6538a317d0b9ec74cc4ac8f375c80c0f2b57223cbd6bb2")
```

```json
{ hash: '0x9117f2fab63c89676b6538a317d0b9ec74cc4ac8f375c80c0f2b57223cbd6bb2',
  nonce: 118329,
  blockHash: '0x02c40394a7ed66bc50a0f1853220a395efd1e3cfebea5e0ff36dd5a0a12b2aeb',
  blockNumber: 3089723,
  transactionIndex: 1,
  from: '0x64DCC3BCbeaE8ce586CaBDef79104986bEAFcaD6',
  to: '0xBEd51D83CC4676660e3fc3819dfAD8238549B975',
  gas: 2000000,
  gasPrice: '60000000',
  value: '0',
  input: '0x5a686699000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032d5284006bf8730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060214e2a000000000000000000000000504efcadfb020d6bbaec8a5c5bb21453719d0e00',
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0x2faaa315b1b3cd7421db1dc5fa243ddfae906282872c2bd9207e7e2dfed8286e',
  s: '0x571fa5a28a48755bdf93aacd28d8d7d8986b1e2db0f5450e2355e7f3c91db30b' }
```

In this case, you get `3089723` from `blockNumber`

Now, you query the current best block:

```sh
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(console.log)
```

```json
3089747
```

And, therefore, you have `3089747 - 3089723 = 24` confirmations.